# Does Gan Eden smell like the havdahlah candle?

Tags: havdalah, smell, gan-eden

I’ve constantly heard from my family that after extinguishing the candles for havdalah you should smell them, I have found sources claiming this helps with smell and with memory but my family claims that the Smokey smell is the smell of Gan Eden. Has anyone else heard that? Do any sources write that?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. Rashi says Gan Eden smells like an apple field. Your question wants to know if the smokey smell of havdalah candles smells like gan eden.

Comment: [This article](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php?title=%D7%94%D7%91%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%94) discusses staring at the four fingers against the havdallah candle and it has something to do with gan eden...

Comment: These things are expounded in different ways. If one wants a more mystical understanding, the way that every smell is unique and indescribable - you can't know it until you smell it - there is going to be some conscious experience of Gan Eden that we can't fathom right now

Comment: @robev "apple field" more like citrus field https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Taanit.29b.2.1 (cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6854/759)

Comment: Tosafos there says תפוח in that context means esrog. How do we know it always means that?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51292/smelling-the-extinguished-havdalah-candle